# python pyramid set throttle policy in download request

Tags: python, pyramid

when a client request for download like

> example.com/media/files/test.mp4

if it is large file like 1gb to 3gb, user request drop in the middle.
My server got hanged and other user can not download file.I want to set throttle bandwidth limit for a single user session in every request.

Comment: Pyramid is the wrong place to do any throttling.

Answer (score 0):

You should use front end web server like Nginx to do the throttling:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html

Python WSGI application is not suitable for this, as specialized front end web servers can do it much better.